# Create a Views Block to show all Node 'Attached Files' as a File list.

Tags: views, files

In creating the CMS structure, I've been trying to do this today, but seem to be getting no where.

I simply want to show all the files as link (PDF, Doc, Docx etc) that have been uploaded by a user to a node type listing which has a Field already created in the Content type structure (by me, the Admin/web) using Views. I've got as far as creating the View with the relevant fields and set it in the Panel Page as a block, but in testing nothing seems to show.

All I require is any relevant 'attached' files related to that Node Content (ie XYZ rock Band, attached mp3 files at bottom of page) so that future readers can click to download to local.

Can someone refresh my memory as how to do it so I can compare where I may be going wrong? I have set the author ID in Relationship, but still the files I have set do not show. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Let me see if I get this: You have a content type A, with a file field. now when you visit a node B, below it you want to display the list of files attached by B's author to all other nodes of type A (as a download link)?

Comment: No not at all; all posts of the designed Content Type have a Field content in it using the 'Field' Type with 'Media Selector' and the file types such as PDF, are stored on the server. The maximum files that can be attached to the Field is five. The user (with permission) can post articles and attached relevant files to their posting. Visitors can view these files and download them as they wish. Very much like when you see a 'Job posting' with attached documents as PDFs below the job posting. I wish to show these as links so people can download them to open. I'm to use a View in  the Panel page

Comment: you can give a try to [download_file](https://drupal.org/project/download_file) module as well.

Comment: Thanks @arpitr I'll checkout download_file although I've already committed to the Node content structure and it may get in the way; but I'll read the docs on https://drupal.org/project/download_file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion above, create a new view, and configure and filter it however you need. the main part is to have the file display as link for download. For this, when you add the relevant field to views, in the settings form, there will be a drop down option for "Link this field to". Choose "File" from there and the field value will be linked to it. Clicking on it will allow the user to download the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Neo that helps. That is sort of what I have been doing, but I cannot remember seeing the 'Link to' element s above. I'll see how I correct it and post my results here for future readers. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your doubt, be sure to mark this as correct answer, so the people looking at this question later will find some help too. Thanks.